# 'List indices must be integers, not tuple' Error when using sep='\n'

Tags: python, list

I made a quick program which outputs the full script of '12 days of Christmas' in a least possible amount of lines.

However when using:

```
print(myList,sep='\n')
```

In the full program:

```
script = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "A patridge in a pear tree", "Two turtle doves and", "Three french hens", "Four calling birds", "Five golden rings", "Six geese a laying", "Seven swans are swimming", "Eight maids are milking", "Nine ladies dancing", "Ten lords-a-leaping", "Elven pipers piping", "Twelve drummers drumming"]
for each in range(1,13):
    print(("On the ") + str(each) + str(script[each - 1]) + " day of christmas my true love gave to me")
    print(script[11 , (each) + 10] ,sep='\n')
```

I get the error message of:

print(script[11 , (each) + 10] ,sep='\n')

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

I have looked online however nothing seems to fit and I am now banging my head against the wall. Anyway thanks for reading.

Comment: What do you intend `script[11 , (each) + 10]` to do?

Comment: You're indexing the list named `script`, but you're giving it two values separated by a comma instead of just one integer value.

Comment: Script will (supposed) to print the script (patridge, turtled doves etc.).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Python does not have the c comma operator.

Comment: @BilltheLizard It is supposed to do that because I want the preogram to print the objects between 11 (patridge in a pear tree) to each + 10. However I get the error message

Comment: Replace `,` with `:`

Comment: The operator you need is `:`.

Comment: I think it is the \n that is causing you the problems. Also change the (each) + 10 to (each + 10) it looks better and makes more sense in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting a comma inside your index to `script` in the expression `script[11 , (each) + 10]`, you are trying to the tuple `(11, each+10)` as an index, which has no meaning for a list.

If you want to print the elements between two indices, you need to use a slice, which uses a colon, not a comma.  For instance, `script[2:5]` would print the elements from indices 2 to 5 (including 2 but not 5).

However, to get the correct song lyrics, you want is to print the elements from `each+11` to 11 in *backwards* order:

```
print(*script[(each) + 11:11:-1] ,sep='\n')
```

This gives the right result:

```
On the 1st day of christmas my true love gave to me
A patridge in a pear tree
On the 2nd day of christmas my true love gave to me
Two turtle doves and
A patridge in a pear tree
On the 3rd day of christmas my true love gave to me
Three french hens
Two turtle doves and
A patridge in a pear tree
[etc.]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to shorten it even more and do something like:                                                                  for each in range(1,13) : print(("On the ") + str(each) + str(script[each - 1]) + " day of christmas my true love gave to me" + '\n') + (print(*script[(each) + 11:11:-1] ,sep='\n'))